# Why is new being used with a function expression?

Tags: javascript

While looking at some source code I found this:

```
require["./helpers"] = new function() {...};
```

Why is `new` being used here? When I run this on JSLint I get

`Weird construction. Delete 'new'.`

So is this just a form of style, personal preference? Or is there something behind this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a way of creating an object which allows `this` to be used during the creation.

This offers some direct reference to the object during instantiation that object literal syntax does not allow.

```
var o = new function() {
    this.num = Math.random();
    this.isLow = this.num < .5; // you couldn't reference num with literal syntax
};
```

The object literal version would need to look like this:

```
var o = {
    num: Math.random()
};
o.isLow = o.num < .5;
```

So the anonymous function is basically used as a temporary constructor. We could just as easily use a named constructor function, but since we don't really care about the constructor, we just use a "disposable" one.

And of course since it's a function, it creates a local variable scope, so if you assign any functions to the new object, they will be able to close over local variables.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically doing the same thing as an IIFE which returns a public interface (an object with public properties/methods which have access to the private scope of the function) of some sort, except for people who ***REALLY AND DESPERATELY*** want to use `this` during the construction, and can't be bothered to use `call`, `bind` or `apply`, or just flat out return a regular inline object.

Under the hood there are a few difference between IIFEs and constructor-functions when both are used in their anticipated ways...  ...but in this instance, there really isn't anything inherently different about the final return value done either way, from a high-level (ie: as far as your program should be concerned).